# Condition based function declarations

Tags: php, code-quality

I recently came across a weird piece of code

```
if(foo == bar){
 function foo_bar(){
   // Function definition
 }
}
```

Is this a good practice of coding ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one valid use case:

```
if( !function_exists("helloWorld") ) {
    function helloWorld() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Other than that, it would be preferable to avoid defining your functions inside if blocks.

Comment: +1, there are enough landmines in PHP without creating your own.